# Parsing expression grammar for a language consisting of sentences with one character added or removed anywhere

Tags: formal-grammars, parsers

Given a parsing expression grammar for a language, is there a way to make a parsing expression grammar for a new language that consists of the valid strings from the original language, plus the strings obtained by adding or removing a single character from an original language string?

Comment: For the related context-free grammar one may add this to an existing grammar. I imagine this is much harder for parsing expression grammars as these avoid ambiguity.